# Start trigger Jenkins Bitbucket Hook

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, ngrok

Hi I have a problem setting bitbucket hook in order to start a Jenkins trigger. 
I installed Jenkins on my local machine ad I use ngrok to create a unique url.
In my bitbucket settings' project page I configured a webhooks in this way

**http://myngrokurl/bitbucket-hook/**

In my Jenkins project, under settings I flagged

**Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket**

But when I push on master branch I see the bitbucket-hook POST in my ngrok console but jenkins doesn't fire.
There is something wrong in my settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem using the generic webhook Trigger Plugin
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to verify the link http://myngrokurl/bitbucket-hook/ if it's accessible in a different network, for example, you're using Bitbucket Cloud

And you may try to enable Build Triggers -> Poll SCM in Jenkins project

Noticed that there is a view request link and allows you to enable history collection, you may want to try out this option and see if the any code push triggers a webhook call
*Discalimer: I never tried this 'view request' personally, because my configuration with webhook link and 'Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket' and 'Poll SCM' combination already works. But I thought this feature may help you to investigate and find out the root cause quickly*